# Storing time in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data like this

Start_time   End_time
12:10:30     13:10:00

I want to store this in pig and calculate elapsed time.
How can i do this in pig ? 
I simply wrote Start_time-End_time but the result is blank

Comment: this has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24448773/3214477)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the difference between start\_times and end\_times in PIG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448004/finding-the-difference-between-start-times-and-end-times-in-pig)

Answer (score 2):

The query will be similar to this:

```
time = LOAD '/user/name/input_folder/file_name' USING PigStorage() AS (sd:chararray, ed:chararray, t1:chararray, t2:chararray);
A = FOREACH time GENERATE $0, $1, GetHour(ToDate(t1,'HH:mm:ss')) as hour1, GetHour(ToDate(t2,'HH:mm:ss')) as hour2;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ($3 - $2) as time_elapsed;
dump B;
```